# Animate a label

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I am trying to animate a label in a WPF application. The label gets created programatically (and dynamically) so it is not defined in XAML, but is created in the C# code.

**Animation Story**

The label appears in the bottom of the window. The label should be positioned lower than the window, so the user can not see it initially. Then a the label moves up (like sliding) and fades out before it reaches the top of the window.

**What I have done**

I have implemented this behavior myself in an other project. This time I want to use WPF which should perform better.

So far I have seen there should be multiple ways of doing this. Starting with a `DoubleAnimation`, going by a `PathAnimation` and `VectorAnimation` (the last of which I have not tested successfully).

**Encountered problems**

The animation works nice with a `DoubleAnimation`, but there is a problem: When I resize the window, the label gets resized too (similar to an anchor in Winforms). When I make the window smaller the label gets smaller too, until it disappears completely. This effect occurs only in the height of the label. I added the code snippet adding the label. Maybe you find some error. Also there should be a better way to implement this (I personally find it very ugly).

```
Label lbl = new Label()
{
    Content = "Test",
    FontSize = 36,
    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
    HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top
 };
lbl.Margin = new Thickness(0, this.MainGrid.ActualHeight + lbl.ActualHeight, 0, 0);
this.MainGrid.Children.Add(lbl);
UpdateLayout();
Transform myTransform = new TranslateTransform();
lbl.RenderTransform = myTransform;
DoubleAnimation AnimationY = new DoubleAnimation((this.MainGrid.ActualHeight + 20) * -1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
myTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, AnimationY);
```

**Questions**

As I said, I have found multiple ways that seem to achieve the same behavior. Which one could I use to do this. I still have to do the fade-out on the top of the window, but this animation is easier to do compared to the movement.

Comment: Have you tried setting the minHeight and minWidth of the label?

Answer (score 0):

The animation is fine. The reason your label is resizing is because you are adding it to a Grid. If you want your label to have a fixed height, then set its [Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height(v=vs.110).aspx) or [MinHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minheight(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: The DesiredSize.Height says it should be 312px... but that is not really an option, it is just a label with 36 font size?

Comment: Try removing the line where you are manually adding a Margin. This appears to be adding a top margin that is larger than the available panel space.

Comment: Yes, but how do I add the label in that position then? The position should be "outside" of the grid, so the label is hidden first and can "appear" by moving up.

Comment: Via the render transform. Set it outside by default, and the animation will override it to animate it back in.

Comment: Yes, but how do i set it outside without changing the margin? I also create this inside the code, because it has to be dynamic.

Comment: As I said, via the render transform. That's what a render transform is for. It displaces the element from it's normally rendered position. So have your transform's normal position be outside. The animation can then override this to bring it inside.